# Bootstrap hide modal button

Tags: jquery, hide, bootstrap-modal

I work with bootstrap and jquery-1.9.1.min.js.

I have the following jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EUSurvey</title>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp"%>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {  

    alert("en function");

    $('#myModalCheck').modal('hide');


});             

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-backdrop="static" class="modal" id="myModalCheck" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><spring:message code="question.SendEmailsNow" /></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a id="btnCancelConfirmFromSendInvitation" onclick="$('#myModalCheck').modal('hide');" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><spring:message code="label.Cancel" /></a>
        <a id="btnConfirmFromSendInvitation" onclick="$('#myModalCheck').modal('hide');" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><spring:message code="label.OK" /></a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Modal bootstrap is

[image]

I want to hide my modal window when I click a button

The modal window doesn't hide.

How can I hide the modal window when I click a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.modal("hide");`

```
  $("#btnCancelConfirmFromSendInvitation , #btnConfirmFromSendInvitation").click(function(){


   $("#myModalCheck").modal("hide");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following , remove the onclick attribute from the links and append this code in a document ready statement

```
$('.modal-footer a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModalCheck').modal('hide');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<a id="btnCancelConfirmFromSendInvitation" onclick="$('#myModalCheck').modal('hide');" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><spring:message code="label.Cancel" /></a>
```

you can use this

```
<button id="btnCancelConfirmFromSendInvitation" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
```